# Twig: Unexpected token "name" of value "as" ("end of statement block" expected)

Tags: symfony, twig, lint, twig-extension

When i run a Twig Lint test localy using CLI on a file, i get no warning.
But, my Gitlab pipeline returns a KO for the same file at the Twig-Lint stage:

> Unexpected token "name" of value "as" ("end of statement block" expected)

Here is my code:

```
{% for subItem in item.subItems %}
    {% if subItem.subIndex is same as eaConst('SUBMENU_INDEX', ea.request)|int 
       and subItem.linkUrl is not same as menuItemUrl
    %}
       {% set submenuItemLabel = subItem.label %}
       {% set submenuItemUrl = subItem.linkUrl %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried this on the 'if' statement, but the error is still here:

```
{% if subItem.subIndex is same as(eaConst('SUBMENU_INDEX', ea.request)|int)
    and subItem.linkUrl is not same as(menuItemUrl)
%}
```

For me everything is correct, i can't figure out what's wrong.
Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Here is the pipeline test failure
https://gitlab.com/solo-projects3/ep-portfolio/-/jobs/2092671708

Comment: What is the reason of the filter `int` at the end of the statement?

Comment: It is a custom twig function i made in AppExtension class.

Comment: From the docs: the correct usage of [`same as(false)`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/sameas.html) is to have the right side of the comparison as a parameter of the word `as`. So: `if subItem.subIndex is same as(eaConst('SUBMENU_INDEX', ea.request)|int) and ...`

Comment: Isn't it what i've done on the correction i tried in my message?
Here is the pipeline failure test: https://gitlab.com/solo-projects3/ep-portfolio/-/jobs/2092671708

Answer (score 1):

Well, as i didn't find any solution, i finally seperated the condition into 2 different 'if' statements:

```
{% if subItem.subIndex is same as(eaConst('SUBMENU_INDEX', ea.request)|int) %}
    {% if subItem.linkUrl is not same as(menuItemUrl) %}
         ...
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

It is verbose, but it works. If anyone have a better solution, i am still interested, as i am facing this issue quite often.